# Slurm migrate DB from Mariadb to mysql enterprise

Tags: mysql, database, migration, mariadb, slurm

I am are trying move from maridb to mysql enterprise and we are not sure how compatible.
Migrating Mariadb DB to mysql will create any issues ?

If we build new cluster can we use mysql enterprise as our DB instead of depending on Mariadb. 
We trying figure out slurm is how compatible with Mysql DB  for accounting and job history ?

Some details about our Infra :
slurm 15.08.8
Mariadb version :  5.5.44-MariaDB

Could someone, please let me know suggestions.

Comment: What does accounting and job history mean in this context? A migration is a major step. I'd at least test mariadb to mysql community edition as a first step and then validation your application is still working as expected.

Comment: "Accounting and job history"  is related to slurm application
https://slurm.schedmd.com 
It's a scheduler it use DB to store above information.

Comment: Slurm does say mysql/innodb - https://slurm.schedmd.com/accounting_storageplugins.html so I wouldn't expect any trouble. Just curious, what are you gaining by the migration?

Comment: We have mysql enterprise, so migration will help us to get support and backup other stuff...

Comment: makes sense. Wouldn't expect a problem, especially from an older mariadb version like 5.5.

Comment: Thanks @danblack